# Why is v-model not working in my Vue component?

Tags: vuejs3

I have the following code...

```
const Blue = {
    props: ['value'],
    computed:{
        onEmit(){
            console.log("Calling");
            return `${this.value} up`
        }
    },
    template: `
        <button @click="$emit('input', onEmit)">Push me</button>
    `
}
export {Blue};
```

I try to use it like...

```
const InnerComponent = {
    data(){
      return {
          blue: "Going"
      }
    },
    template: `
      <div>
         <h1>{{blue}}</h1>
         <blue v-model="blue"></blue>
      </div>
      
    `
}
export {InnerComponent}
```

But when I click the button the `<h1>` doesn't change. What am I missing? How do I use v-model?

This works fine but I was under the impression I could replace the `:value` and `@input` with `v-model`

```
<blue :value="blue" @input="doInput"></blue>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it looking at [this](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-basics.html#using-v-model-on-components)...

```
const Blue = {
    props: ['modelValue'],
    emits: ['update:modelValue'],
    computed:{
        onEmit(){
            return `${this.modelValue} up`
        }
    },
    template: `
        <button @click="$emit('update:modelValue', onEmit)">Push me {{this.modelValue}}</button>
    `
}
export {Blue};
```